# RIP 'I amsterdam', when will I see you again?

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, locate-this, nostalgia

Due to over-tourism, they removed from the center, but a colleague from NET told me they will put it back somewhere else.

Is this true? If so, does anyone know when and where?

[image: telegraph]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems they will come back, but when and where is still unknown. From local news site [AT5](https://www.at5.nl/artikelen/189153/i-amsterdam-letters-verwijderd-na-opknapbeurt-elders-in-stad-terug) (December 3rd):

> Ze worden opgeknapt en daarna zullen ze rondreizen door de stad. Welke plekken ze zullen aandoen, is nog niet bekend.

DeepL Translate:

> They will be restored and then they will travel around the city. The places they will visit are not yet known.

---

The [Parool](https://www.parool.nl/amsterdam/i-amsterdam-letters-mogen-blijven-bij-sloterplas-en-in-zuidoost~a4606276/) newspaper reports other places where you can still visit similar letters (there are 5 sets in total): Presumably you can still see them at [Schiphol Airport](https://goo.gl/maps/q3n1STqd2sy), at the [Hoekenrodeplein](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hoekenrodeplein,+1102+BR+Amsterdam) (haven't found this one yet) and near the [Sloterplas](https://goo.gl/maps/nnuUxvjBNCH2).

Comment: The one at Hoekenrodeplein was by the small green mound just outside the train station.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [I Amsterdam](https://www.iamsterdam.com/nl/op-bezoek/over-amsterdam/i-amsterdam-letters) characters page of the I Amsterdam website, the characters are traveling around:

- Schiphol (airport)
- Sloterplas in Amsterdam West (free running track, hard to make a good picture)
- One set travelling around through events/festivals. (see the website)
- Traveling set currently at Amsterdam Zuidoost at Hoekenrodeplein (Station Bijlmer ArenA).
- A'DAM Lookout at Overhoeksplein near the water IJ in Amsterdam North.

Comment: Yes, I saw them already in a friend's photograph in Facebook - however I don't recall where was the photograph from.

Answer (score 3):

There still is a i Am Amsterdam sign at Sloterplas. Its a lake in New West Area. Take 17 from Central and go out in Osdorp. Abouit 30 min with tram. You see a lake and on one side there still is a sign ;)